# Cause of looping function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

https://pastebin.com/fZsTQLTP

I am making a browser based math game and have run into a looping error.

The numbers are generated between 0 and 20 and are generated again if their sum or difference (when applicable) falls outside 0 or 20.

```
function mathFunction() {
        //generates a value of 0 or 1 to dermine if the problem will be addition or subtraction (0 = + , 1 = -)
        var sign = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        if (sign == 0) {
            dsign = " + ";
        } else {
            dsign = " - ";
        }
        //generates two random values between 0 and 20
        var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
        var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
        //if the sum of an addition problem is greater than 20, it calls mathFunction to make new values
        if (sign == 0) {
            if (num1 + num2 > 20) {
                mathFunction();
            }
        //if the difference of a subtraction problem is less than 0, it calls mathFunction to make new values
        } if (sign == 1) {
            if (num1 - num2 < 0) {
                mathFunction();
            }
        }
```

The variables are sent to the evaluation function.

```
//evalFunction is called when the button is clicked, and passes the 2 numbers and the sign value
        document.getElementById("enterButton").addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
            evalFunction(num1, num2, sign);
        }, false);
    }
    function evalFunction(num1, num2, sign) {
        var counter = 1;
        alert("fire");
        var answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
```

I have added alerts to help keep track of things.
Pressing enter the first time will result in a normal outcome.
Pressing enter after the first problem will cause errors that seem to be the result of the functions looping.

```
        //calls mathFunction to generate a new question
        alert(counter + " num 1: " + num1);
        alert(counter + " num 2: " + num2);
        alert(counter + " answer: " + answer);
        counter = counter + 1;
        mathFunction();
    }
    //loads first question
    window.onload = mathFunction();
```

I have pasted the entire code in pastebin. Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

The looping error is due to `mathFunction()` calling itself if it's invalid.

So the call stack looks something like this:

```
mathFunction() --> mathFunction() --> mathFunction()
```

When the mathFunction at the top of the stack finishes, the next `mathFunction()` continues executing, as if nothing had happened.

Instead of having `mathFunction()`, try having a function that returns a math problem as an object:

```
function generateProblem() {
    //generates a value of 0 or 1 to dermine if the problem will be addition or subtraction (0 = + , 1 = -)
        var sign = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
        if (sign == 0) {
            dsign = " + ";
        } else {
            dsign = " - ";
        }
        //generates two random values between 0 and 20
        var num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);
        var num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21);

        //return the problem as an object
        return {sign: dsign, first: num1, second: num2};
}
```

Then put this problem-generator function in a loop:

```
var problem;
while (true) {
    problem = generateProblem();
    //checks for addition, you can expand it to check for valid subtraction questions as well
    if (problem.sign == " + ") {
        if (problem.first + problem.second == 20) {
            continue; //this problem isn't valid, so restart at the top of the loop
        }
    }
}
```

In summary, the mathFunction() sometimes calls itself. When this happens, the result is that the functions pile up. To prevent this, put the problem-generation in a function, and the problem-checking in a loop. This way, the call stack won't pile up with mathFunction().